# Selecting a Material Texture by Name

Tags: python

Is there a simple script I can use to select a Material texture by name? I have many textures, each ending with a new suffix Texture.001, Texture.002 etc..
I am using a Cloud Texture. I may want to select Texture.002
Below is a photo. Essentially I would like to select Texture.002 with python script. With the object being select, linking the Texture.002 to the object.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "selecting" a material? In blender you can either create or assign materials. Consider each material can have multiple slots... so **please take your time and put more effort into your questions**: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Perhaps the photo and edit helps explain.

Comment: can you tell us what your "end" goal is? to you want to rename textures? or assign them to materials? do you want to assign a texture (with specific name) to many materials?  or...?

Answer (score 0):

If you click that same spot - its easy to miss because its at the bottom but there is a search box there that you can type text into to get your texture.

Comment: I need to select the material with python code and assign it to my object which is selected

Comment: gotcha - sorry that was unclear to me on first reading...